# Can i use UI-select component in a widget?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, widget, ui-select

I'm attempting to use the UI-select component for the Category in a widget. I haven't had any luck finding a resource that shows it is possible. My question is if i can use UI-select component as shown in the image below in my widget and if so how to do it.

[image]

Note: I have added the UI-select component to ui_component/form.xml but i wanted to show in the widget to give a better user experience.
The code im talking about:

```
 <field name="category_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category</item>
            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category_id</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
            <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```